# Contradictory answers when finding oblique asymptotes

Tags: calculus

When finding the oblique asymptotes of $y=\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}$, I have been taught two approaches. The first is to split the fraction into $x-1+\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ which approaches $x-1$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

The second is to rewrite the expression as $\dfrac{x}{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}$, which approaches $\dfrac{x}{1+0}=x$ as $x$ approaches infinity. After graphing the function on Desmos, I know that only the first method works, but I don't see why it shouldn't for the second answer since we do it all the time when evaluating limits.

Comment: $\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}$ approaches $\dfrac1{1+0}$ but$\dfrac{x}{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}$ does *not* approach $\dfrac{x}{1+0}$

Comment: Careful with what you call "*approach*". Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+1/x}$, $g(x)=x$ then indeed $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/g(x)=1$, but this does not mean $g(x)$ is an asymptote of $f(x)$. For that you need $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) - g(x) = 0$ which does not hold true.